# Node runs out of memory on Heroku but not on localhost

Tags: node.js, memory, heroku

My node worker is running out of memory on Heroku and my Heroku worker is restarting itself in the middle of processing a message in the queue. When I run the same exact code on my localhost (on macbook) memory is reclaimed and it never goes above 120mb or so.

What could be possible reason for this out of memory error on production environment ? Do we need to handle memory managment in Heroku ? Is there something about Heroku that I don't know regarding memory ?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Node.js locally?  You can explicitly set a version to run on Heroku.

Comment: how many messages has it processed?

Comment: @Jon `node -v` on my local machine returns `v0.10.1` and i've got this is my package.json: `"engines": {
        "node": "0.10.x"
    }`

Comment: @tgkprog It's only trying to process 1 message. I am using [Kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue)

Comment: So what version is it running on Heroku @BenSlayton?  I'm going to guess 0.10.3. Why not ensure they're exactly the same - and then check for leaks? Ie. change your engines to 0.10.1 say.

Comment: @JonMountjoy I changed it to 0.10.1 on heroku and still the same issue. :(

Comment: enable runtime metrics and tell us about what it is saying.

Comment: Are you running the same code with the same level of traffic? Traffic / jobs require memory, so running a one-off worker locally won't simulate the same sort of behavior you'll see in a worker that's really being used. For instance, do you run out of memory if you create a new instance of your worker on Heroku and run the same test you're running locally?